# Overriding style that already has !important

Tags: angular

If I want to override some css from my component child, I just use:

```
:host ::ng-deep .y {
     x: !important;
}
```

but how to override a style that already has `!important`? The above example in this case won't work

Comment: You would have to make the CSS selector more specific. Can you show the HTML markup of the element and the context around it? If you could make a stackblitz showing the problem, that would be even better.

Comment: The original style: .sortable-container .sortable-list .active

I tried: body .sortable-container .sortable-list li.active

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
:host /deep/ .y
```

instead of

```
:host ::ng-deep .y
```

I use :host /deep/ .y in my Angular application and works perfectly

Comment: _::ng-deep, /deep/ and >>>_ are deprecated.

Comment: This doesnt help :(

Answer (score 0):

Going from your comment about the original code this should probably work:

```
:host ::ng-deep .sortable-container .sortable-list ul .active {
  x: value !important;
}
```

This assumes you're in a 'ul' but it could be ol or dl and replaced just as easily.

Comment: Don't forget the `li` in `li.active`.

Comment: He shouldn't need it. The ul is an inserted element above the .active so it is more specific.